# Can I install GNU Hurd in Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, software-installation

Is it possible to use HURD Kernel on ubuntu(any version)? It would be good to see other kernels running with ubuntu. But I really wonder is it even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. [According to the Hurd project](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd/running/distrib.html), there is only one working distribution with Hurd, and that is [Debian GNU/Hurd](http://www.debian.org/ports/hurd/), which is in development.

However, you can run the [available image](http://people.debian.org/~sthibault/hurd-i386/debian-hurd.img.tar.gz) in Qemu.

If you want to run in on hardware, check the [GNU/Hurd Hardware Compatability Guide](http://www.nongnu.org/thug/gnumach_hardware.html)
.

Comment: But why can not we use another kernel? Is it like that we can use only Linux with Ubuntu or there are some other kernels out there??

Comment: Because there is no demand for it. Supporting multiple kernels is a complication that is simply not worth it. With the current Debian release you can use the FreeBSD kernel, but as a separate architecture, not as a simple package with the kernel.

Comment: @Egil Not the only one : http://www.archhurd.org/

Comment: @user43790 Even on the Arch Hurd website the maintainer admits he can't get it working with Arch and is running Debian Hurd for his testing.