# Can I install Hurd in Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, software-installation

I was thinking that, if Ubuntu is based on Debian, and Debian has the GNU Hurd, why there's not an Ubuntu GNU/Hurd? Is there a possible way to install GNU/Hurd in Ubuntu? Thanks

Comment: This would be really cool...but if Ubuntu is to add other kernels, we should probably add [kFreeBSD](http://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/) first, as that is now [ready to use for general-purpose applications, and almost stable, in Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_GNU/kFreeBSD).

Comment: Duplicate of: [Can I install GNU Hurd in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37945/can-i-install-gnu-hurd-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a good idea, but I don't think it would be widely used. For one, I'm pretty sure that programs compiled for Linux don't run under HURD. This would force people to change their system with a clean install. Not many people want to do so. This leaves new users. Most new users don't know much about this system, so why would they use the not-quite-ready HURD system over a Linux system that everyone here won't shut up about? The only way people would use this is if they can set up dual-boot and use their old programs without a clean install (it would have to be a quick sudo aptitude install hurd-kernel).

I was reading about GNU HURD and its advanced structure, Debian is deploying DEBIAN GNU HURD and it would be very interesting to se how it works as a desktop system althou it is "still" (about 15 years) in developement and still not production ready (missing support for a lot of hardware - no sound support).

more info about HURD can be found on wikipedia or on http://www.gnu.org